# TransitionDrawable causing ANR in android

Tags: android, transitiondrawable

im having an issue with TransitionDrawable class in android causing an ANR in strict mode. Here is the method call causing the ANR:

```
private void crossFadeImages(Drawable imageToFadeOut, Drawable imageToFadeIn) {
    TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable( new Drawable[] {
            imageToFadeOut,
            imageToFadeIn
    });
    m_myimageView.setImageDrawable(td);
    td.startTransition(200);
}
```

i am passing two drawables. the imageToFadeOut has the following specs:

**337X599 PNG (32-bit color) 93.85KB**

and the imageToFadeIn has the following specs:

**337X599 PNG (32-bit color) 395.16KB**

and the ANR is being caused in a nexus 5 emulator api 19 xxhdpi. The actual ANR shows up in strict mode mostly.

i get the following log error

`"I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."`

the method is called from the main thread. How can i resolve this ? Or is there another way to do the cross fading between two images ?